# everything left-aligned and small margins using parallax.js

Tags: javascript, css, html, parallax.js

I'm using parallax.js for a website, and I've run into a bit of a problem.

It seems that everytime I want to scroll a div in from the right, everything in the div that I'm scrolling in, is aligned quite sharply to the left, and the content of the div is all squished up against the left margin.

I'm demonstrating what I mean here:
http://jsfiddle.net/gS8YU/8/

Am I doing something wrong? You'll see that the div named `test` loads correctly, but when scrolling in from the right, it gets all distorted.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the div a fixed width:

```
#test
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[see HERE.](http://jsfiddle.net/gS8YU/11/)